# PHP rand minimal chain length

Tags: php, mysql

Rand function generates the bank account number in my PHP web application.
What can I do to make the generated numbers always `10 numbers` and that they never repeat? for example: `0000000000`, `0232346522` etc...

```
$r_nrkonta = rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

Edit:
what should I do to generate again bank number?

```
    $r_nrkonta = rand(1000000000, 9999999999);

    $rezultat2 = $polaczenie->query("SELECT numerkonta FROM kontabankowe WHERE numerkonta='$r_nrkonta'");
    if (!$rezultat2)
        throw new Exception($polaczenie->error);

    $ile_takich_nrkonta = $rezultat2->num_rows;
    if ($ile_takich_loginow > 0)
        // generate again r_nrkonta ??
```

Comment: Characters or numbers? You use both in your question. If numbers, do you want from `1000000000` to `9999999999`?

Comment: $new = rand('1000000000','9999999999');you need to check it the database if it is there then generate a new one

Comment: Please tell me this is just an exercise or is this for a real bank?

Comment: @juergen, only exercise haha. this is my private project

Comment: @Andreas, I edited my post.

Comment: the only solution is save it in database and check whether that number exist or not.

Comment: @tarangP, I edited my post. what should I do to 'generate again bank number?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `while` structure:

```
$exist=true;

while ($exist==true) {
    $r_nrkonta = rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
    $rezultat2 = $polaczenie->query("SELECT numerkonta FROM kontabankowe WHERE numerkonta='$r_nrkonta'");
    if (!$rezultat2)
        throw new Exception($polaczenie->error);

    $ile_takich_nrkonta = $rezultat2->num_rows;
    if ($ile_takich_loginow <= 0)
            $exist=false;
}
```